# Wordpress Neptune Theme Issues (specifically with the home page photo grid)

Tags: image, wordpress

I want to do a complete makeover of my website, as I am not very fond of the design I have right now. The theme I have in mind to switch to is [Neptune](http://www.wpexplorer.com/neptune-wordpress-theme). I've tried to switch my site over, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get images that I post to show on the front page. I basically just want my home page to look like the demo page of the theme with a grid of images (but of course with my images). I have tried making new posts...I've tried adding a new item to the "portfolio" section on the left hand bar, but nothing seems to be working.

Just in case it is of any help, [the theme I have now is Cloriato Lite](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/cloriato-lite).

Comment: Can you provide a URL to your website so that we can try and troubleshoot?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Does the theme come with documentation? You might have to setup the homepage as a static page on the reading settings page.

Comment: Well it says to go into the reading settings and make sure it's set to the defaults, but I don't know what the default settings are...

Comment: Default is to display latest posts.